# Spinner "text size"

Tags: android, spinner

Alright. I have gone through various posts in stack overflow as to how to change the "text size" of an entry in spinner but none of them seem to be helpful. My porblem is, i have a spinner widget which is referencing an array of elements. I just need to change the text size of the array of elements.

```
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, LinkActivity!</string>
<string-array name="Gender">
<item>  Male    </item>
<item>  Female  </item>
<item>  Transgender </item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

I just need to change the text size of the "item" elements which are "male" "female" "transgender".

Comment: The string resource xml file is only for strings. No theming, layouts and so on. So in the layout file you use the string, you have to add your attributes to make it look like you want.

Comment: @Cheesebaron: where do i add the attributes!?

Comment: Try show us where you are using your items.

Comment: I got the solution ... http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2010-07/msg00494.html

Comment: Which is exactly what both Jimmy and I said you should do.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a new XML layout file that will be used to determine the layout of each item within your spinner. In my case, this meant making a file called "fat_spinner_entry.xml" and putting it in my res/layout directory that looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:margin="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

The key thing in that xml is that I upped the textSize from the default spinner text size.

Next, you'll need these two lines:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
mySpinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.strings, R.layout.fat_spinner_entry));
```

Where R.id.mySpinner is the id you assign your spinner in the layout (not shown here, I assume you already have one,) R.array.strings is the strings array that normally is assigned as entries in your layout XML (again, not shown here, I assume you already have one,) and R.layout.fat_spinner_entry is the layout that I described at the start.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add: `android:textSize="24.5sp"` inside your spinner tags in the "class xml file" (not the string resource xml)